# File read from ADLS Gen2 Error - Configuration property xxx.dfs.core.windows.net not found

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, apache-spark-xml

I am using ADLS Gen2, from a Databricks notebook trying to process the file using 'abfss' path.
I am able to read parquet files just fine but when I try to load the XML files, I am getting the error the configuration is not found - Configuration property xxx.dfs.core.windows.net not found.

I haven't tried mounting the file but trying to understand if it's a known limitation with XML files, as I am able to read the parquet files just fine.

Here is my XML libraries config
com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.9.0

I tried a couple of things per the other articles but still getting the same error.

- Added a new scope to see if it's a scope issue in the Databricks Workspace.
- Tried adding configuration
  spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net", "xxxx==")

```
df = spark.read.format("xml")
 .option("rootTag","BookArticle")
 .option("inferSchema", "true")
 .option("error_bad_lines",True)
 .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
 .load(abfsssourcename)   ##abfsssourcename is the path of the source file name

Exception Details: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1113.load. 
Configuration property xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net not found. at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:392) at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:1008) at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:151) at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:106) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:500) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:469) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:1281) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:1269) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:820) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1269) at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile$.withCharset(XmlFile.scala:46) at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:71) at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:71) at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:43) at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:42) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation.<init>(XmlRelation.scala:41) at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$.apply(XmlRelation.scala:29) at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:74) at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:52) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:311) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:297) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:214) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: The package seems using RDD API to read xml file, so we need to save the key in Hadoop configuration options. Please update code as `spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.key.xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net", "xxxx==")`. For more details, please refer to https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#rdd-api

Comment: @JimXu, this line of code fixed the issue. I used mount as alternative solution, but your response is the answer to my question :)

Comment: Hi. I summarize my suggestions as a solution. Since it is useful for you, could you please accept it as an answer? It may help more persons who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing, accepted it as answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

The package `com.databricks:spark-xml` seems using RDD API to read xml file. When we use using the RDD API to access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2,  wecannot access Hadoop configuration options set using `spark.conf.set(...)`. So we should update the code as `spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.key.xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net", "xxxx==")`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#rdd-api).

Besides, you aslo can mount Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 as file system in Azure databricks.